# Rails group_by query with parent & child records

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get all the users who may `Buy` `Sell` or `Create` by counting the time like the below

> ***I want to like this below example***

```
2021 (0)

2020 (0)

2019 (4)
    January (2)
        -> Buy (1) // Specifically with records date if possible
        -> Sell (1)
    
    August (1)
        -> Create (1)

    September (1)
        -> Buy (1)

2018 (3)
    January (2)
        -> Buy (1) // Specifically with records date if possible 
        -> Sell (1)
    
    August (1)
        -> Create (1)


And so on........
```

And I was trying something like below

```
// controller 

@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@records = @user.records.joins(:task)
.where(tasks: {name: ["Buy", "Sell", "Create"]})
.group_by {|t| t.created_at.beginning_of_year}


// view.html.erb


<% @records.each do |y, h| %>
    <%= y.strftime("%Y") %>
    <% h.each do |f| %>
        <%= f.task.name %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

Output like below

2018 
    Buy 
    Sell
```

here are below my models & tables, I was trying several ways but still didn't get that.

```
//table users
has_many :records, dependent: :destroy

--------------------
id | name | etc... |
--------------------
1  | john | etc    |
--------------------
2  | alex | etc    |
--------------------

//table tasks
has_many :records, dependent: :destroy

-------------
id | name   |
-------------
1  | Buy    |
-------------
2  | Sell   |
-------------
3  | Create |
-------------

//table records
belongs_to :task, required: true
belongs_to :user, required: true
    
-------------------------------------
id | user_id | task_id | created_at |
-------------------------------------
1  | 2       | 2       | timestamps |
-------------------------------------
2 | 1        | 1       | timestamps |
-------------------------------------
3 | 1        | 2       | timestamps |
-------------------------------------
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: While you have done a decent job on communicating your schema I'm missing a clear example of the expected output and what you have attempted. Also [#group_by` is a method from Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) so it will load the records from the database an iterate across them as if it was an array - this can lead to performce problems and may produce very different results.

Comment: If you want to add a GROUP BY clause to a SQL query you want to use [`group`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-group).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of querying the user query the records table directly with the `user_id` and the task names then perform 3 `group_by`(s) first `group_by` is on the year the
the task was created the second group_by is for the month and the third is for the task name

### The code to look up the task

```rb
records = Record.joins(:user, :task).where(users: {id: @user.id}, tasks: {name: ["Buy", "Sell", "Create"]})
records_grouped_by_year = records.group_by { |e| e.created_at.year }.sort.to_h
# now you will get a list of tasks in a hash with keys as years { 2018 => [record1, record2, record3, record4]}


records_grouped_by_year_month = records_grouped_by_year.transform_values { |records| records.group_by { |r| r.created_at.strftime("%B") }) }
# now you will get a hash inside a hash first key is year second key is month the record was created in { 2018 => {"January"=>[record1, record2, record4], "August" => [record3]}

records_grouped_by_year_month_name = records_grouped_by_year_month.transform_values { |records| records.transform_values { |record| tasks.group_by { |r| r.taks.name } } }
# now you will get 3 nested hashes first key is year second key is month and third key is the record name { 2018 => {"January"=>{"Sell=>[record1, record2], "Buy=>[record4]}, "August" => { "Buy" => [record3]}}}

(records.key.first..Time.current.year).each { |year| records_grouped_by_year_month_name[year] ||= {} }
# now it will add an empty hash for each year that didn't exists in the records
```

## In your view:

```
<% task_count_grouped_by_year_grouped_by_name.each do |year, data_by_month| %>
    <h1>  <%= year %> </h1>
    <% if data_by_month.blank? %>
        <%= there was not sale on this year %>
    <% else %>
        <% data_by_month.each do |month, data_by_name| %>
            <h2>  <%= month %> </h2>
            <% data_by_name.each do |task_name, records| %>
                <br /> <bold><%= task_name %></bold> -> (<%= records.count %>) <% # 
    you have the records here as an array so you can do whatever you want with them %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: No, the `Task` model is independent, the `task_id` is the `records` table same like as `user_id` on the `records` table.

Comment: @user9769384 updated so it query the records now

Comment: let me try this

Comment: I think it is working but need to apply with full data like 10 millions

Comment: do you mean you're worried about the performance? you should have an index on `user_id` and an index on `task_id` already in your DB because of the association if you don't you should definitely add them and probably make sure you have an index on the name of tasks - you could also go back to your original query: `records = @user.records.joins(:task).where(tasks: {name: ["Buy", "Sell", "Create"]})` the added group_by iteration should not take much time but to be fair this is an elaborate view if it does it's a worth trade-off IMO

Comment: I think the codes are working but there is a problem like I want the years by consequences like if that starts from `2015` then need to show every year on that list sequencially whether if data present or not like `2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020 2021...`

Comment: currently, it's showing the year only if has data, otherwise skipped the year, any idea, please.

Comment: what do you need it to show if the search year is empty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231258/discussion-between-mshka-and-user9769384).